# Uncle blocks and their Relationship to Chain Size

Tags: blockchain, storage, blocks, uncle-blocks

How much do uncle blocks affect the overall chain size? Is the amount of added security they provide for the chain comparable to how much extra data they add to the chain?

If, for some reason, all uncle blocks were wiped from the Ethereum chain, how much smaller would an archive node's data be?

EDIT: Is there a way to estimate the size of a block based on the transactions in it? As in, can I go on etherscan and look at a block and estimate the size of it?